# Micronaut - What is the @ModelAttribute equivalent

Tags: spring, micronaut, modelattribute

In Spring I know I can bind thymeleaf form inputs to a command object using @ModelAttribute in the controller, but is there an equivalent in Micronaut? I can't see it documented anywhere

Comment: See https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.7/guide/#formData

Answer (score 2):

Mapping form data in Micronaut is straight forward.

Given a form containing two input fields

- `<input name="name"/>`
- `<input name="location"/>`

you can handle them on the backend either

## Binding them to parameters

```java
@Controller("/form")
public class FormController {

    @Post
    public HttpResponse processForm(String name, String location) {
        return HttpResponse.created();
    }

}
```

or

## Bind form data to POJO

```java
public class MyForm {

   private String name;
   private String location;

   // getter/setter omitted
}
```

```java
@Controller("/form")
public class FormController {

    @Post
    public HttpResponse processForm(@Body MyForm) {
        return HttpResponse.created();
    }

}
```